# What is the interpretation of the magnitude of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, products

Consider a vector $v$.

The magnitude of this vector (if it describes a position in euclidean space) is equal to the distance from the origin:

$$(v^Tv)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{(v^Tv)}$$

that is, the square root of the dot product.

Suppose we compute this value for not just a vector but a matrix M, which describes an operator that transports a position vector.

What is the interpretation of the magnitude?

Comment: Compute *what* value? The matrix square root of $M^TM$?

Comment: yes that is what i meant

Comment: What do you mean with "transport a position vector?"

Comment: Would you really want to call the square root of a matrix a *magnitude*?

Comment: You multiply a vector by a matrix and then you end up with a new vector... hence transport (like its moved? or u can use the word projected)... i suppose magnitude is just the word we call these htings

Comment: The square root of a matrix is hard to define.

Comment: I think the word you were looking for is transform.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Assuming $M$ is a real matrix, $M^TM$ is a positive matrix, and for positive matrices the square root is easily defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\sqrt{v^Tv}$ is just the Euclidean norm $\|v\|_2$. There are infinitely many different norms for vectors and any one of them gives rise to a legitimate measure of "magnitude".

The same also holds for matrices. You can measure the "magnitudes" of matrices by using [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). If you stack up the columns of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ successively with the first column on top, you get a long vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. The Euclidean norm of this vector (i.e. $\|v\|_2$) is called the *Frobenius norm* of the matrix and it is denoted by $\|A\|_F$. Again there are other kinds of matrix norms as well.